# Descrypt pgp_sym_decrypt (PostgreSql) text in c#

Tags: c#, database, postgresql, encryption, helper

I have an application that uses C# to API  and Postgrel for database. I need encrypted columns in my tables and I used the PGP_SYM_ENCRYPTfunction with the "KEY" key. Now I need to decrypt this data in the API with EF Core. But I have no idea how to do it.

Example:

One encrypt into postgresql:

```
select PGP_SYM_ENCRYPT('marco stuff', 'key')::text
```

this return a hex:
"\xc30d04070302d642c54f7d22dcae67d23c019e9ceb839a26a14e689886c8c632a580fa95670dade158502e3f3b9033b4a94fa2c4917c040a7cf83b6d7060c3ed0e7967600f3ddbe8df077fc25d"

To Descrypt this with postgre we use this:

```
select PGP_SYM_DECRYPT('\xc30d04070302ca0d35a3d9b814f07fd23c01b1f8caf67bb860fe4c403a6f300390a79cbbe804c14f6d2a1a2b9912dfc9c9094eedea6dd293d14e801cf61cb138ad829449675c3530c42f8410be', 'key')
```

But, i need descrypt this hex using csharp, and i don't have idea. Could someone help me or give me a parameter?

Eu tentei muitas coisas, usei Lybrary BouncyCastle, Aes etc. Mas nada me ajudou, preciso descriptografar estes dados com CSharp.

Comment: All algorithm are usually not compatible

Comment: Hello @nbk, the main goas is crypt and decrypt in csharp and on postgresql, in this example I use PGP_SYM_ENCRYPT, but if exists other and you know, will help-me. What is needed is to be able to perform the same "encryption" and "decryption" in both postgre and csharp. Can you help-me?

Comment: you can try the openpgp library https://didisoft.com/net-openpgp/examples/encrypt-file/ postgres says it is compatible, so give it a try

Comment: "This example" is the only specific thing there is in your question.  If your question is not about "this example", then you have asked the wrong question.

Comment: @jjanes sorry but this is the first time that I use StackOverflow. My need is can cryptography data columns by postgre. I can, but, only by database with function "PGP_SYM_ENCRYPT". Now, I need to decrypt this data by cSharp.

Comment: @nbk - I see this forum, but, I neet descryptgraphy the data of database colum. Example, I have one table in database postgre: 
**create table user(name TEXT).**

I have a Insert in this table: Insert into user (name) 

**select PGP_SYM_ENCRYPT('Leo', 'key')::text**
this command insert a data cryptography, name value "\xc3..." and now I need descryptography by CSharp

Comment: no you would SELECT the data again from the database using the postgres decrypt function, the rest is a normal sql SELECT, of which you find millions of examples, no need to get c# otherwise involved

Comment: @nbk, is that I currently use entityframework core for involvement with postgresql.. in this case I don't use selects to pull the data, I use 100% the entityframework. Do you know how I could wrap postgre's decryption function using EFCore 7? Thanks in advance for your support

Comment: then you need to make qa user defined function and and map oit or use raw sql,

Comment: @nbk You have a example that how i can map a function with EFCore to get a descrypt?